# IntelliJ: Scala code doesn't compile when Play 2.0 plugin is installed

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 13.  I have a Play 2.0 project and a separate Scala project.  When I install the Play 2.0 plugin (version 0.30.379) and open just the Scala project, the Scala compiler stops working.  When I remove the Play 2.0 plugin, I can see that the Scala compiler is working when doing a rebuild (it shows up in the status area then).

If I remove the Play 2.0 plugin and use the Play 1.x plugin, Scala compiles fine.  Reverting to previous versions of the Scala and Play 2.0 plugins doesn't seem to help (I reverted to versions prior to february 2014).

I tried a fresh install of IntelliJ but no luck.

Any ideas?

*I've also posted this issue in the Jetbrains issue tracker here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-120990  I'll update this if I find out anything.*

Comment: This may likely be related to http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-6704

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a bug in Intellij 13.0.2+ and may work fine in 13.0.1.  I'll test that and update this answer.